# How to set the Parent Control from WinForms Designer in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer, splitcontainer

I am building my user interface in Visual Studio and I've noticed that there is not a ***set parent*** property in a control's property toolbar.

I am wondering why this is so, and if there is a clean way to enable this feature. If it's not possible, why isn't it available?

An example of why I need it is that when I'm using a `SplitContainer` and `Panel1` has 10 child panels all with Dock mode set to `Fill`, it becomes incredibly difficult to add a new panel to the `SpitContainer`'s `Panel1`.

Visual Studio always assumes that I'm trying to place my new panel as a child of the most-forefront panel already present.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you not use the document outline window? [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46xf4h0w.aspx). This will allow you to re-arrange the control hierarchy and child controls.

Answer (score 2):

this can be access via code, but not in the designer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx

Property is inherited from Control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent.aspx